# Como referenciar apenas as primeiras ocorrências de uma tag A utilizando jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Eu tenho o seguinte HTML:

```
<div class="block_content_inner">
<div class="details_block">
    <b>Title:</b>
    "Titulo do Filme"
    <b>Genre:</b>
    <a href="#">Action</a>
    <a href="#">Adventure</a>
    <a href="#">Fantasy</a>
    <div class="director_row">
        <b>Director</b>
        <a href="#">Diretor 1</a>
        <a href="#">Diretor 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="director_row">
        <b>Studio</b>
        <a href="#">Studio 1</a>
        <a href="#">Studio 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="director_row">
        <b>Serie</b>
        <a href="#">Nome da Trilogia</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Eu preciso referenciar as 3 primeiras tags `<a>` que estão logo após a tag `<b>Genre</b>`, porém pode acontecer de ter 1 tag `a` ou várias, precisaria ser de uma forma dinâmica.

Eu quase consegui, porém em uma tentativa traz apenas o valor da primeira tag `<a>` ou traz valores de todas as tags `<a>` que estão nessa div, inclusive as que estão dentro da `<div class="director_row">`

Eu precisaria do valor das tags `<a>`após a tag `<b>Genre</b>` e antes da div `<div class="director_row">`.

Eu não posso manipular o HTML, preciso apenas referenciar do jeito que já existe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o método `.prevUntil()`, selecionando a primeira div com a classe `.director_row`. Irá pegar todos os elementos entre a primeira `div.director_row` e o elemento `<b>Genre:</b>`:

```js
var els = $(".director_row:first").prevUntil("b");

// só exemplo para ilustrar
// os links ficarão vermelhos
els.each(function(){
  $(this).css("color", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="details_block">
    <b>Title:</b>
    "Titulo do Filme"
    <b>Genre:</b>
    <a href="#">Action</a>
    <a href="#">Adventure</a>
    <a href="#">Fantasy</a>
    <div class="director_row">
        <b>Director</b>
        <a href="#">Diretor 1</a>
        <a href="#">Diretor 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="director_row">
        <b>Studio</b>
        <a href="#">Studio 1</a>
        <a href="#">Studio 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="director_row">
        <b>Serie</b>
        <a href="#">Nome da Trilogia</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Usando nextUntil()

Outra forma é começar pegando o primeiro link `<a>` até o último anterior à `div.director_row` usando `nextUntil()`:

```js
var els = $(".details_block a:first")
         .nextUntil(".director_row")
         .addBack();

// exemplo para alterar as cores
// não inclua no seu código
els.each(function(){
  $(this).css("color", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="details_block">
    <b>Title:</b>
    "Titulo do Filme"
    <b>Genre:</b>
    <a href="#">Action</a>
    <a href="#">Adventure</a>
    <a href="#">Fantasy</a>
    <div class="director_row">
        <b>Director</b>
        <a href="#">Diretor 1</a>
        <a href="#">Diretor 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="director_row">
        <b>Studio</b>
        <a href="#">Studio 1</a>
        <a href="#">Studio 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="director_row">
        <b>Serie</b>
        <a href="#">Nome da Trilogia</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

> **Nota:** se tiver usando uma versão anterior a 1.8 do jQuery, use `.andSelf()` no lugar de `.addBack()`.

Comment: Muito interessante esses métodos pra criar um range de seleção!

Answer (score 2):

Não necessariamente precisaria de jQuery, o que vc tem que se atentar é ao seletor.

No CSS

```
.details_block > a { }
```

No jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".details_block > a").addClass('minhaclass');
});
```

Isso pega apenas os `<a>` filhos diretos de `.details_block`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".details_block > a").addClass('minhaclass');
});
```

```css
.details_block > a {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.minhaclass {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="block_content_inner">
 <div class="details_block">
  <b>Title:</b>
  "Titulo do Filme"
  <b>Genre:</b>
  <a href="#">Action</a>
  <a href="#">Adventure</a>
  <a href="#">Fantasy</a>
  <div class="director_row">
   <b>Director</b>
   <a href="#">Diretor 1</a>
   <a href="#">Diretor 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="director_row">
   <b>Studio</b>
   <a href="#">Studio 1</a>
   <a href="#">Studio 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="director_row">
   <b>Serie</b>
   <a href="#">Nome da Trilogia</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *"que estão logo após a tag <b>Genre</b>"*  o seletor `".details_block > a"` funcionaria para esse caso, para as tags exatamente após a tag "b"?

Comment: @RicardoPontual sim funcionaria, o "problema" é que ele pega todos os <a> filhos diretos, não importando a posição, significa que se tiver um <a> lá no final depois da última row ele tb será selecionado. Mas como no código dele não tem esse outro elemento, achei que poderia ser de alguma utilidade, já que seleciona apenas os elementos descritos

Comment: Boa resposta, mas me parece que ele quer selecionar os elementos para fazer alguma manipulação via jQuery, e não para mudar estilos. Logo via CSS me parece não ser útil neste caso. :/ Vamo ver o que ele vai dizer. Se for apenas para mudar estilo, vai escolher a sua resposta; :D

Comment: Ah tah rs... não tinha visto a parte com o jQuery pegando os filhos diretos. É uma forma legal tb, desde que ele não invente de adicionar posteriormente outros links dentro da div rs.

Comment: @Sam eu eu tinha colocar com jQuery depois, ai ele pode manipular como quiser. Essa questão que vc levanto as vezes me frusta um pouco. Pq a gente da uma resposta que funciona para o que foi postado na pergunta.... Ai depois que a gente responde, vêm as "replicas" *e se isso*, *e se aquilo*... ai complica rss. No caso se ele tv qualquer outro <a> filho direto o seletor tb vai pega-lo, mas como na pergunta não tem, achei que essa seria uma resposta condizente :), mas se ele falar que tem mais uma <a> filho direto que ele não quer pegar minha regra vai cair, ou vou precisar de um .not() talvez

Comment: Entendo e acho exagerado mesmo prever possibilidades que poderão inutilizar a resposta, mas acontece muito por aqui de nêgo levar -1 na resposta porque a abordagem não prevê possibilidades. Eu particularmente não dou -1 em respostas assim, a não ser que seja algo gritante. Mas tá de boa. Muitas vezes quando a resposta não prevê possibilidades, o AP aparece no outro dia pedindo correções rss... tmj

Comment: @Sam temos alguns usuários que são especialistas nisso :/

Comment: @hugocsl Todas as respostas foram boas, algumas não atingiram meu objetivo porém me ensinaram coisa nova. Agradeço pelo tempo reservado para me auxiliar. Escolhi a outra resposta como correta apenas por ser um pouco mais completa, mas ambas atingem meu objetivo. Obrigado também por me ensinar algo novo.

Comment: @D.Watson tranquilo jovem não se preocupe com isso, eu que fico feliz em ajudar! []´s

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro precisamos achar o elemento da tag "b" que tenha o conteúdo "Genre":

`$("b:contains('Genre:')")`

Depois, os próximos 3 elementos da tag "a". Para isso usamos `nextAll`, para obter os próximos elementos no mesmo nível, depois usamos o `lt(x)` para pegar os "x" elementos que desejamos:

`nextAll("a:lt(3)")`

O código completo fica como abaixo, e mudei o estilo para demostrar o seletor funcionando:

```js
$("b:contains('Genre:')").nextAll("a:lt(3)").css('color','red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block_content_inner">
<div class="details_block">
    <b>Title:</b>
    "Titulo do Filme"
    <b>Genre:</b>
    <a href="#">Action</a>
    <a href="#">Adventure</a>
    <a href="#">Fantasy</a>
    <div class="director_row">
        <b>Director</b>
        <a href="#">Diretor 1</a>
        <a href="#">Diretor 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="director_row">
        <b>Studio</b>
        <a href="#">Studio 1</a>
        <a href="#">Studio 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="director_row">
        <b>Serie</b>
        <a href="#">Nome da Trilogia</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: O método `:lt` é mt bom, mas, como o número de tags `<a>` pode ser variável, usar um valor fixo `3` não vai funfar.

Comment: sim, eu só usei ele pra atender o *3 primeiras tags"* da pergunta, mas ele realmente é fixo :(